# How often TLS handshake should happen?

Tags: ssl, https, client-server, tls1.2

I understand that  TLS handshake is  done at the beginning of a session and is mainly about generating the  symmetric key that is used to encrypt all later communications.

once the handshake is completed, then how often this handshake should happen (regenerate symmetric key) ?

where the symmetric key is stored on client side(browser) ?

how the server identifies the client on server side ?

Comment: It depends entirely on the configurations at both ends: how often the session should be re-keyed and how long a session should last. No single answer.

Comment: any advisable or standard timeout

Comment: Several minutes for the key; an hour or more, maybe even 8, for the session. It depends totally on your requirements.

Comment: In https connections how the server will identify the client

Comment: The symmetric key is not stored anywhere normally for good reasons, except in memory. The server can authenticate the client in the exact same way the client authenticate the server: using X.509 certificates. The change of keys during a session is triggered by a KeyUpdate record as explained in RFC8446 (TLS 1.3)